# Java string null check by != null or !str.equals(null)?

Tags: java, string, null, null-check

What's the best way to check for not null values in java.

```
String query ="abcd";
```

`query != null` vs  `!query.equals(null).`

which is better?why?

Comment: .equals defaults to == as long as it's not explicitly overridden.

Comment: @JaynathanLeung. Are you talking about `String` objects too?

Comment: @RohitJain are there any types of `String` which aren't objects? There is no primitive equivalent as far as I know...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*1st one is better* (and the **only option**), because *2nd one* will throw `NPE`, when your value is actually `null`. *As simple as that.*

Try this out:

```
String str = null;
str.equals(null);  // will throw `NPE`.
```

So basically, the test which you wanted to perform itself triggers a `NullPointerException` in the 2nd case. So, it is no choice.

Comment: NPE = NullPointerException for those who don't know the acronym

Comment: This is wrong.`String.equals` will not throw a NPE.Since it checks for `instanceof` which does not throw exception for `null`

Comment: "Better" is an extreme understatement here.  Second doesn't do at all what you expect.

Comment: @RohitJain:I did:`String test = "aa";
  System.out.println(test.equals(null));`.Prints `false`

Comment: @Cratylus - now try it with `String test = null;` and see what happens...

Comment: @Cratylus what rohit meant was to try `String s= null; s.equals(null)`

Comment: @djechlin. Right. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Cratylus. Why would he test for `non-null` if there is no possibility of `null` value at all? And if there is a possibility of `null` value, then there is `NPE` in 2nd case.

Comment: thanks for the response, that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 11):

`!str.equals(null)` will

1. always return false if it does not throw an exception, and
2. throw an exception if str is null

The point of a null check is to make sure the reference, in this code `str`, actually refers to an object.  If it is null, you can't call *any* methods on it, including `equals`, without throwing a `NullPointerException`...  which the point of null checks is to avoid happening.

So `!str.equals(null)` causes the very problem null checks are meant to prevent and doesn't do what you think at all.  Never do this.

Comment: +1, i made the same point about `str.equals(null)` would always return false, but my answer not clear about the concrete question.. :)

Answer (score 2):

`query != null` better as `!query.equals(null)` will throw an exception when query is actually null. Also `query != null` is easily readable

Answer (score 2):

`query != null` compares if the object is `null`. `query.equals("something")` compares the value inside of that object. `string == "something`". so in this case use `query != null`.